# Using the rigorous definition of limit to prove it

Tags: calculus, definition

Question: Let $\left \{a_n\right \}^\infty_{n=1}$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=1$ and $a_n\neq n\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.
Prove that: $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n+a_n^2}{n-a_n}=1$

I tried to simplify $|\frac{n+a_n^2}{n-a_n}-1|<ε$, and I get that it equals to $|\frac{a_n^2+a_n}{n-a_n}|$, then I don't know what to do next.

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsll2.png)

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Please show us your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. For formatting help, See: [Mathjax help page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). For future reference, I would request you to read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) page which will help you familiarize yourself with asking questions on this website. Thanks!

Comment: I updated it, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: You don't need an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, but an $\epsilon-N$ proof, the limit is to infinity !

Comment: I didn't find this mistake. What should I notice when proving those the limit is to infinity?

Comment: No, that is *not* the goal and it's rather meaningless.  $|n-1|$ will never be $|n-1| < -\delta < 0$.  Ever.  ANd you'd only want an $|n-1| < \delta$ if you are trying to find $\lim_{n\to 1}$.  If you are trying to find a $\lim_{n\to \infty}$ you need to find and $N$ so that $n > N\implies $ what you want.

Comment: Please also include the question as text.

Comment: The definition of $\lim_{x\to k} b_x = L$ is that for any $\epsilon > 0$ you can find a $\delta > 0$ so that $|x - k| < \delta \implies |b_x - L | < \epsilon$.


But that is *NOT* the definition of $\lim_{x\to \infty} b_x = L$.

The definiton of $\lim_{x\to  \infty} b_x = L$ is that for any $\epsilon > 0$ you can find an $N$ so that if $x > N\implies |b_x - L| < \epsilon$.

So for a specific $\epsilon > 0$ you need to find an $N$ so that whenever $n > N$ we will have $|\frac {n+ a_n^2}{n-a_n} - 1| < \epsilon$.

Comment: I fixed it. But I still have no idea after I simplify it to $\frac{a_n^2+a_n}{n-a_n}$, or I shouldn't simplify it? I think I got lost here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: From what you have, you can continue by noting that since $a_n \rightarrow 1$, it must be bounded above for large enough $N$. Similarly, $N-a_n$ will be larger than any prescribed integer $M$ when large enough.

Solution: Remember, we are given any $\epsilon$ and for each one must return an $N$.

By definition of limit, for any $\epsilon_1$, there is $N_1$ such that for all $n>N_1$, $|a_n-1|<\epsilon_1$; let's use $\epsilon_1=1$. We would have $(*) |a_n^2+a_n| < |a_n|^2+|a_n|< 2^2+2=6$. This gives us $|\frac{a_n^2+a_n}{n-a_n}| < \frac{6}{|n-a_n|}$.

Next we want $n$ to be large enough such that $|\frac{6}{n-a_n}|$ is bounded by the given $\epsilon$ and this is done by giving it an upper bound and try to bound that with $\epsilon$. Using the inequality $a_n < 2$, we have  $(**) |\frac{6}{n-a_n}| < \frac{6}{|n-2|}$. Then to finish off, we want $(***) \frac{6}{|n-2|}<\epsilon$, which you would solve it to be $n > \frac{6}{\epsilon}+2$.

Summarizing, we have inequality $(*)$ and $(**)$ because of $n>N_1$ and we then have inequality $(***)$ because of $n>\frac{6}{\epsilon}+2$. So all in all, for any $\epsilon$, we return $N = \max (N_1, \frac{6}{\epsilon}+2)$.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Why can we let $\epsilon_1=1$? Isn't $N$ the number we're finding and $\epsilon$ should be available for any number?

Comment: Sorry just found a typo at the end $N = max(N_1, ... $. We can choose $\epsilon_1 =1$ because that is for $a_n$ and not for the sequence in question. In the process of finding the $N$ for the $\epsilon$, we want $a_n$ to be sufficiently well behaved and therefore we must make sure $N$ always big enough to make sure that happens. Choosing $\epsilon_1=1$ doesn't affect our search for $N$.